# Sequence number based on set of values in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a temp table like this.

DECLARE @temp TABLE
(PID INT)

```
INSERT INTO @temp values(1)
INSERT INTO @temp values(1)
INSERT INTO @temp values(1)
INSERT INTO @temp values(1)
INSERT INTO @temp values(2)
INSERT INTO @temp values(3)
INSERT INTO @temp values(1)
INSERT INTO @temp values(1)
INSERT INTO @temp values(4)
INSERT INTO @temp values(4)
INSERT INTO @temp values(5)
INSERT INTO @temp values(5)
INSERT INTO @temp values(5)
INSERT INTO @temp values(6)
INSERT INTO @temp values(6)
```

SELECT * FROM @temp

```
PID
1
1
1
1
2
3
1
1
4
4
5
5
5
6
6
```

OUTPUT: I want to give a sequence number for each set only based on next value.

```
 PID Sequence
  1    1
  2    2
  3    3
  1    4 
  4    5
  5    6
  6    7
```

I tried all possible ways. Nothing worked. Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: For this to work, you need some column that can be used to order the records. Do you have such column in your data, maybe a primary key column or so?

Comment: No. I don't have any other column. Just based on the next value, I need to increment the sequence number.

Comment: But there is no notion of *next* value unless you have a column that can be used to define the order of the records...

Comment: We can use PID right. Based on the PID value we need to give the sequence number. Example:  1's set is repeated two times but each set has different sequence number. Based on the PID next value, I need to increment the sequence number. Need a query on @temp table

Comment: SQL doesn't do loops and sequence of operations, it operates on and returns sets of values. Your set of input data (PID) is stored in the database with no metadata about the order it is inserted. Thus the order it comes out is simply an accident of the retrieval process. On more complex tables, which have been subject to multiple inserts and deletes, there is no telling what order the data will come out. Which is why there is an ORDER  BY clause to sort the output. Because the database doesn't know the insert order, there is no way to use it in the query.

Comment: Note that most DBMS provide an extended version of SQL for use in stored procedures, which can implement loops. However you will still have the issue of the order the data is returned in your loop not necessarily matching the order you created it. You need either another column, or metadata such as a rowid() or ROWID pseudo-column. Note that these are DBMS-specific extensions to SQL.